# Strange cygwin shell pasting issue

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm running cygwin on Windows 7 and am seeing something really strange. In the cygwin bash shell, any command I run is run with the current copy of the Windows clipboard immediately appended.

For example, if I just copied a Windows path (e.g. c:\Users\foogit) to paste somewhere else, then opened a cygwin prompt and typed 'ls', it would try to run: lsC:Usersfoogit

which would, of course, cause problems.

I can work around it for now by always ending a command with a semicolon, so it tries to do that second part as its own command, but it's been rather frustrating. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe : (echo; echo "export TERM=cygwin") >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Except now it's back.. :(

Comment: (echo; echo "export TERM=cygwin") >> ~/.bashrc